# How do I upgrade ReSharper in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I have [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) 7 installed against Visual Studio 2012 and am looking to upgrade to version 8 now that I have purchased an upgrade license.

How do I upgrade?

Do I have to uninstall then reinstall, or can I apply my license code within Visual Studio via the ReSharper options and it automatically takes care of the update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just follow the installation instructions on the download page and it will upgrade you automatically. The old version will be uninstalled and the new version installed in its place. You won't be able to have both versions installed simultaniously.

Answer (score 2):

The new version needs to be downloaded from the [JetBrains website](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/) and then installed over the existing version.

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/

There are several options when installing the new version, you can run both versions simultaneously or automatically uninstall previous versions.

Comment: This answer is not correct as stated. You could install multiple versions only if you have multiple versions of Visual Studio installed, with a version of ReSharper per Visual Studio however that also depends on which versions of ReSharper you have installed/trying to install.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Installation_Guide.html#platform

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but in the newer versions of VS (2019 in my case) and/or ReSharper, there is a menu option from within VS to check for updates.

Extensions --> ReSharper --> Help --> Check For Updates

Then follow the bouncing ball to upgrade the components you have installed.  You need to restart VS after the install for it to take effect though.